# Table access rowid not work in this query

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to avoid TABLE ACCESS FULL in execution plan but it doesn't work even when I force the index /* index( ) */ in this query :

```
SELECT 
    af.ID, af.nom_flux, st.chemin_stockage, af.hash_flux 
FROM 
    stockage st 
INNER JOIN 
    allotissement_flux af  ON EXISTS (SELECT *
                                      FROM signature sig
                                      WHERE st.id_flux = sig.id_flux
                                        AND af.ID = sig.id_flux
                                        AND sig.statut_signature = 'SIGNE'
                                        AND sig.nb_appel_service_signature < 4 
                                        AND sig.date_statut_signature >= sysdate - 1000)
WHERE 
    st.statut_stockage = 'OUI'
    AND st.date_statut_stockage >= sysdate - 1000
```

The index is created on each attribute of tables.

```
Plan hash value: 2782848463
 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name               | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |                    |    40M|  8376M|       |  1594K  (1)| 00:01:03 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN           |                    |    40M|  8376M|  4284M|  1594K  (1)| 00:01:03 |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN          |                    |    40M|  3821M|  1505M|   543K  (1)| 00:00:22 |
|   3 |    SORT UNIQUE       |                    |    40M|  1042M|       |   146K  (1)| 00:00:06 |
|*  4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| SIGNATURE          |    40M|  1042M|       |   146K  (1)| 00:00:06 |
|*  5 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL | STOCKAGE           |    48M|  3322M|       |   130K  (2)| 00:00:06 |
|   6 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL  | ALLOTISSEMENT_FLUX |    49M|  5527M|       |   536K  (1)| 00:00:21 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - access("AF"."ID"="SIG"."ID_FLUX")
   2 - access("ST"."ID_FLUX"="SIG"."ID_FLUX")
   4 - filter("SIG"."NB_APPEL_SERVICE_SIGNATURE"<4 AND "SIG"."STATUT_SIGNATURE"='SIGNE' 
              AND "SIG"."DATE_STATUT_SIGNATURE">=SYSDATE@!-1000)
   5 - filter("ST"."STATUT_STOCKAGE"='OUI' AND "ST"."DATE_STATUT_STOCKAGE">=SYSDATE@!-1000)
```

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Tag only with the database you are really using.  The code looks like Oracle, so I left that.  Also, sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXISTS` in the `JOIN` condition will not give you good performance.

You should use simple join conditions. Try the following:

```
SELECT af.ID, af.nom_flux, st.chemin_stockage, af.hash_flux 
FROM stockage st 
INNER JOIN allotissement_flux af 
   ON af.ID = st.id_flux -- join condition
WHERE st.id_flux IN ( SELECT sig.id_flux --moved this logic in WHERE clause
        FROM signature sig
        WHERE sig.statut_signature = 'SIGNE'
        AND sig.nb_appel_service_signature < 4 
        AND sig.date_statut_signature >= sysdate - 1000
        )
AND st.statut_stockage = 'OUI'
AND st.date_statut_stockage >= sysdate - 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

I would start by phrasing this as a normal `join`:

```
SELECT af.ID, af.nom_flux, st.chemin_stockage, af.hash_flux 
FROM signature sig JOIN
     stockage st 
     ON st.id_flux = sig.id_flux JOIN
     allotissement_flux af 
     ON af.ID = sig.id_flux
WHERE sig.statut_signature = 'SIGNE' AND
      sig.nb_appel_service_signature < 4 
      sig.date_statut_signature >= sysdate - 1000 AND
      st.statut_stockage = 'OUI' AND
      st.date_statut_stockage >= sysdate - 1000;
```

It is unclear what indexes would work best, but the following should be considered:

- `signature(statut_signature, date_statut_signature, nb_appel_service_signature, id_flux)`
- `stockage(statut_stockage, date_statut_stockage, id_flux)`
- `allotissement_flux(id)` -- you probably have this one already

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way:
use parameter '+outline' in dbms_xplan format parameter - it will show you outline section where you can take outline hints, modify required and add as a hints.

PS. That's not good idea to use exists() in ON section - CBO converts ANSI syntax to own native syntax, so your hints may become invalid.